# SQL Select case

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following sql tables

```
oitems table

    +---------+-----------+----------+
    | orderid | catalogid | numitems |
    +---------+-----------+----------+
    | O737    |       353 |        1 |
    | O738    |       364 |        4 |
    | O739    |       353 |        3 |
    | O740    |       364 |        6 |
    | O741    |       882 |        2 |
    | O742    |       224 |        5 |
    | O743    |       224 |        2 |
    +---------+-----------+----------+

Orders table
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|         orderid | ocardtype  |   odate    |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|     O737        | Paypal     |            | 'OK
|     O738        | MasterCard | 01.02.2012 | 'OK
|     O739        | MasterCard | 02.02.2012 | 'OK
|     O740        | Visa       | 03.02.2012 | 'OK
|     O741        | Sofort     |            | 'OK
|     O742        |            |            | 'ignore because ocardtype is empty
|     O743        | MasterCard |            | 'ignore because Mastercard no odate
+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

the reusltant datatable called `result`

```
 +-----------+----------+--------------+
| catalogid | numitems | ignoreditems |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|       353 |        4 |            0 |
|       364 |       10 |            0 |
|       882 |        2 |            0 |
|       224 |        0 |            7 |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

idea is to sum the numitems column for products that have the same `catalogid` depinding on the data in the `oitems` table with the following conditions

1. if `ocardtype` is empty then ignore the `numitems` and consider it
       as `0` in the sum and sum the ignored items to the `ignoreditems`
       column
2. if `ocardtype` for some order is `MasterCard` or `Visa` and
       the `odate` is empty then ignore the `numitems` and consider it as
       `0` and sum the ignored items to the `ignoreditems` column
3. if `ocardtype` is `Paypal` or `Sofort`, then just do the `numitems`
   sum
       without checking the date because those types require no `odate`

basicly i want to save the result datatable to a temporary datatable and load it to a vb.net datatable

i am having a hard time figuring out how to do this in an sql query! i need this as sql command for vb.net , was able to do it programmatically using vb.net datatables using loops and alot of checking
using linq is an option, but i just need to get this from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select catalogid, numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems
from (
  select i.catalogid,
    sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                   ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                   odate is not null) AND NOT EXISTS (
                     select * from booked b
                     where b.ignoredoid = o.orderid
                   ) then numitems
                   else 0 end) numitems,
    sum(numitems) allitems
  from orders o
  join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid
  group by i.catalogid
) X
```

Comment: The OP has referred to both `ocardtype` and `odate` as potentially being "empty" - yet you've interpreted that in *one* case to be "the empty string", and in another as "NULL". (Aha, sneaky edit I see :-))

Comment: @Damien - I use `col > ''` when I want to simultaneously exclude NULL and ''. Because it's easy and works. But yes, I've taken even that out since it falls into ELSE easily.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi one more thing please, in another table called `booked` i have a column called `ignoredoid`, this columns contains orderids from the above table that i want to ignore even if the conditions above are right, so how can i do this, something like `WHERE orderid does not exist in column ignoredoid of table booked`

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi thank you very much, sql is really cool and i should start learning it!

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi Hello, i've update the question, can you please check the last part?

Comment: You really should ask that as a new question instead of evolving a single question. I'm off to sleep so good luck with it.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi i did! :) and still no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674363/sql-add-processed-ids-to-a-single-cell-seperated-with-a-comma

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT
     oi.catalog_id,
     SUM(CASE
            WHEN ocardtype in ('Paypal','Sofort') THEN numitems
            WHEN ocardtype in ('Mastercard','Visa') and odate is not null THEN numitems
            ELSE 0 END) as numitems,
     SUM(CASE
            WHEN ocardtype is null then numitems
            WHEN ocardtype in ('Mastercard','Visa') and odate is null THEN numitems
            ELSE 0 END) as ignoreditems
FROM
   oitems oi
      inner join
   Orders o
      on
         oi.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY
   oi.catalog_id
```

(Assuming that wherever you've used the word "empty" in your narrative, you mean the column is `NULL`)

Comment: I would -1 this for logic, but I'll let it pass. It reads like the OP wants the 2 sums to be complementary, but however I look at this, there will be cases where they won't add up to the total.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Linq-to-sql version of your original request (as a LINQpad query):

```
Dim odateRequired = {"MasterCard", "Visa"}
Dim odateNotRequired = {"Paypal", "Sofort"}
Dim result = From o In Orders Join i In Oitems On o.orderid Equals i.orderid _
             Let check = o.ocardtype IsNot Nothing _
                     AndAlso ((odateRequired.Contains(o.ocardtype) _
                               AndAlso o.odate IsNot Nothing) _
                        OrElse odateNotRequired.Contains(o.ocardtype)) _
         Group By i.catalogid Into _
         numitem = Sum(If(check, i.numitems, 0)), _
         ignored = Sum(If(check, 0, i.numitems))

result.Dump
```

Your extra request in the comments to RichardTheKiwi's answer (it just includes `Not (From b In Bookeds Where b.ignoredoid=i.orderid).Any AndAlso` at the front of the `check`):

```
Dim odateRequired = {"MasterCard", "Visa"}
Dim odateNotRequired = {"Paypal", "Sofort"}
Dim result = From o In Orders Join i In Oitems On o.orderid Equals i.orderid _
             Let check = Not (From b In Bookeds Where b.ignoredoid = i.orderid).Any _
                     AndAlso o.ocardtype IsNot Nothing _
                     AndAlso ((odateRequired.Contains(o.ocardtype) _
                               AndAlso o.odate IsNot Nothing) _
                        OrElse odateNotRequired.Contains(o.ocardtype)) _
         Group By i.catalogid Into _
         numitem = Sum(If(check, i.numitems, 0)), _
         ignored = Sum(If(check, 0, i.numitems))

result.Dump
```