# Multiple columns in Linq left outer join

Tags: vb.net, linq, outer-join

Could somebody help me complete this linq left outer join query so that the second column of the right table (tempData) is contained in the result set even though it may be null?

```
sortedData = From cs In mbCustomSort
             Order By cs(0)
             Group Join entry In tempData On cs(joinColumn) Equals entry(0) Into Group
             From last In Group.DefaultIfEmpty _
             Select New With {.groupField = cs(joinColumn)}
```

Comment: What are mbCustomSort, customsort and tempData?

Comment: Sorry, mbcustomsort and tempData are datatables. customsort should read cs

Comment: Does this work: `Select New With {.groupField = cs(joinColumn), .SecondRight = last(1)}`?

Comment: Unfortunately not - though why I don't know.

Comment: It returns "Object reference not set yo instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I write in C#, but how about:

```
var sortedData = from cs in mbCustomSort orderby cs.JoinColumn
    join entry in tempData on cs.JoinColumn equals entry.OtherJoinColumn into Group
    from subentry in Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { groupField = cs.JoinColumn };
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't that still only return one column?

Comment: What would you like it to return?

Comment: How about `select new { groupField = cs.JoinColumn, subentry }`

Comment: I want to return the first column of the left table and the second column of the right table (null or not). And, yup, I've tried that one too.

Comment: select new { groupField = cs.JoinColumn, subentry } works but the column of the result set is an array and it is confusing to see how to return the elements in it.

Comment: your select clause would be like `select new { DesiredOutputNameOfFirstColumn = cs.FirstColumn, DesiredOutputNameOfSecondColumn = subentry.NameOfSecondColumn }`

Comment: I tried the following: `sortedData = From customsort In mbCustomSort _
                         Order By customsort(0) _
                         Group Join entry In tempDataQuery On customsort(joinColumn) Equals entry(0) Into Group
                         From subentry In Group.DefaultIfEmpty _
                         Select New With {.groupField = customsort(joinColumn), .total = subentry.total}` but I get a pre-compile error of "total is not a member of System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: It means that `subentry.total}` is referring to something that does not exist (subentry does not have a property called `total`). Are you trying to sum up a field in subentry? Try `.total = Group.Sum(columnToSum)`

Comment: So groobie, did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)

The `From last In Group` turns the outer join into an inner join. This does not happen when you continue with the `Group` variable:

```
sortedData = From cs In mbCustomSort
     Order By cs(0)
     Group Join entry In tempData On cs(joinColumn) Equals entry(0) Into Group
     Select New With {.groupField = cs(joinColumn), 
                      .col2 = Group(1).RightColumn }
```

Change `RightColumn` by the property of "In-memory Query" object.

Comment: That nearly does it but the contents of the second column in the result set holds an object called "In-memory Query" that contains both columns from the right table - but thanks for getting closer to the solution. Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: OK, so it might be something like `From row In Group Select row(1).RightColumn`?

Comment: I haven't got enough details to know where to go now. Can you get it working by changing it, helped with intellisense and all?

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad's default processing doesn't allow for `item(fieldno)`, so I used actual field names in data repurposed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12668630/256431), including adding a new row in `Mbc` with no corresponding `OrderId` in `Mbtd`. This works for me:

```
From cs In Mbcs _
Order By cs.Catalogid _
Group Join entry In mbtds On cs.OrderId Equals entry.OrderId Into Group _
From last In Group.DefaultIfEmpty _
Select cs.OrderId, last.Ocardtype
```

And by "works" I mean the row I added appears with a *null* `Ocardtype` (as well as another row where `Ocardtype` was already `null`).